# retrieve and display data using $user_id

Tags: php, mysql

My aim is to display a clip of a user's bio data from the users table in mysql database
whenever a user makes a post to be diplayed on a feeds-view.php page just as
is obtainable in facebbok and twitter using the $user_id passed along with the message to the 
posts table in mysql db when a user makes a post.
So I'm trying to use the $user_id of the user(who made the post) to query their bio data from the users 
table in the database. I'm looking to display an image and a few other info such as
name, phonenumber etc. and also to create a kind of loop so subsequent posts assume same 
template or structure. The code I devised below failed. Please I need help on this.

secondly,
I attempted using session variables to transfer data from users table to posts table as a way to 
obtain bio data of a signed in user to be displayed when a post is made
but I was stymied at transfering a session variable containing an image(jpeg) example
is $image = $_SESSION['image']; as I tried to transfer the value to posts table
to be displayed in feeds-view page, it says
"Error You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
 MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '﻿' id='W5M0MpCehiHzreSzNTczkc9d'?>"

Target:
Is to display bio data (i.e image, name etc) of the user who makes a post or whose post
is being displayed on the feeds-view.php page and also to create a kind of loop so subsequent posts assume same 
template or structure.

```
            <?php
           session_start();
           if(!isset($_SESSION['username'])){
            header('location:landing page.php');


      include_once('server.php');
      //include_once('server2.php');

       function load_user_objects($user_id){

      $query = "select * from clientcompany where id = '$user_id'"; 

      $result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);

      if (!$result){
      return "no user found";
     }
    return $result[0];
    }   
    }

    ?>



   <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>W3.CSS</title>
     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    </head>
    <body>

    <div>
     <?php
    include_once('server.php');
      $sql = "SELECT * FROM post ORDER BY DESC";
     $result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);

      function load_user_objects($user_id){
       $query = "select * from users where id = '$user_id'"; 

      $result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);

       if (!$result){
       return "no user found";
      }  
       return $result[0];
     }

    function do_news_feed($user_id){
        $status_objects = $this->get_status_objects($user_id);

    foreach($status_objects as $status){?>
    <div>
     <?php $users = $this->load_user_objects($status->user_id);?>



    <?php       //this attempts to display foto of a user who makes a           post. Image accessed from users table.
       include_once('server.php');
       function getimage($user_id){ 
       $query = "SELECT image FROM users WHERE id = '$user_id'";  
         $result = mysqli_query($conn,$query);
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
     {
      echo $users->'<img src="data:image/jpeg;           base64,'.base64_encode($row['image']).'"class="w3-circle" alt="userfoto"     

        style="width:100px; height: 100px; margin-top: 70px; margin-left:             20px">';
       }
       }

       ?>

         <?php // this attempts to access the users table to display data              using the load_user_objects function
         echo $users->name;
         ?>
         <?php
         echo $users->location[posts table][1];
         ?>  


          <?php // this attempts to access the posts table to display data.
         echo $status->title;
          ?>
          <?php 
        echo $status->message;
         ?>

        </div>
        <?php
         }
          }
          ?>
         </div>
        </body>
       </html>
```

Comment: SELECT * FROM post ORDER BY DESC, order by what?

Comment: order in DESC... starting with the most recent.

Comment: Can you leave ORDER BY blank? I have never tried it. Maybe it defaults to the primary key or something? I would specify a column after it to see if that fixes the error.

Comment: hi, my codes aren't working. It doesn't display. That's the problem. Please read the first verse. In the feedsview.php page, I'm trying to access two tables to pull data. Pls read above

Answer (score 0):

Probably you get that error on MariaDB because you have this line wrong (you send MariaDB to order the rows by an empty field):

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM post ORDER BY DESC";
```

Reading your question, I supposed you want to order all the rows by "id" field so you must replace the wrong line for this one:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM post ORDER BY id DESC";
```

That way MariaDB won't throw that error and you can keep developing your idea

Comment: Hi Julio... the error with maria db comes sessions variable. I was trying to pass logged in users image to posts table along with a message but that error comes up. I was using sessions there not querying the db.

Comment: I'd appreciate if we stick to the first as I failed to upload the code containing the session variables.